# Hyperlink to Different URI Scheme using PHP+HTML

Tags: php, iphone, ios

Alright, I have the following page: mydomain.org/register?referral=iphone_app

I have the following code:

```
<? $token = 123;
$referral = $_GET['referral'];
$url = $referral.'://account-link?token='.$token; 
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Link your account</a>'; ?>
```

This code links to the following URL:
http://mydomain.org/iphone_app://account-link?token=123

I would like it to link to: iphone_app://account-link?token=123.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `$_GET['referral']` contain?

Comment: Obviously $_GET['referral'] is being assigned the value 'http://mydomain.org/iphone_app' for some reason.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/fL7Qx/ I believe the browser is not seeing the http:// protocol (or a recognized protocol) on the link href and adding the current page.

Comment: Well, I'm a little confused. The OP says if he puts the plain ANCHOR with the appropriate url, then it works, but the PHP version doesn't... Which does suggest it's a problem with how the url is being built.

Comment: I updated the post to provide a bit more info.
Also, I just tried using HTML to output the link (without variables) and it didn't work - it still returns http://mydomain.org/iphone_app://account-link?token=123

This will be used to open an iOS application.

Comment: If you take the `$referral` out and just do `$url = 'iphone_app://account-link?token='.$token;`, it doesn't work?

Comment: @Jared, nope, it doesn't. It still returns mydomain.org/iphone_app://account-link?token=123

Comment: Is there a way for you to view the actual source? I think it may be that the browser doesn't understand the protocol to open `iphone_app://` and thus adds the current page's uri to the link href. For instance, in your try the jsfiddle in my link above and see if it adds the http://jsfiddle.net/ uri to the link href.

Comment: @Jared, I tried your jsfiddle example and it did indeed add the jsfiddle.net uri to the link.

When viewing the source, it looks fine - the current page's URI doesn't get added. I think you may be right.

Comment: I don't know if you have an installation process for what you're doing, but if you do, I think you might have to add a protocol handler to the device for the app you're trying to open. You might read up on "ios add protocol handler" in Google results. For instance, this looks promising: http://blog.agiletortoise.com/post/1555040022/protocol-handlers-and-2-way-app-integration-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

Would really need to know what $_GET['referral'] contains, or what it *should* contain, before we can make any educated guesses.

Assuming that it contains the page the user just came from, that value should be expected and you should be able to use preg_match() or explode() to grab what you need (the last bit). Something like...

```
preg_match($referral, "/^.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_])*$/", $matches);
```

The fact that it is working directly in the HTML *should* point to a PHP mistake.

Comment: I think it's possible that the browser doesn't understand the `iphone_app://` protocol. See the last few comments below the question.

Comment: $_GET['referral'] contains 'iphone_app' in my example, and it should contain the name of the referring application.

I was mistaken, it's not working directly in the HTML after all - initially I thought it was. `<a href="iphone_app://account-link?token=123">Link your account</a>` doesn't work.